# Unable to find fallback package folder "NuGet & VS2019" Error

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

How to resolve this issue? VS2019
Just created a new .Net Core 3.1 Windows Application and built the Project

I was not able to follow this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62586350/nuget-packaging-core-packagingexception-unable-to-find-fallback-package-folder)! it is not clear

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB4018 The "ResolvePackageAssets" task failed unexpectedly.
NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackagingException: Unable to find fallback package folder 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\NuGetPackages'.
   at NuGet.Packaging.FallbackPackagePathResolver..ctor(String userPackageFolder, IEnumerable`1 fallbackPackageFolders)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.NuGetPackageResolver.CreateResolver(IEnumerable`1 packageFolders)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.NuGetPackageResolver.CreateResolver(LockFile lockFile)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheWriter..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader.CreateReaderFromDisk(ResolvePackageAssets task, Byte[] settingsHash)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ReadItemGroups()
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ExecuteCore()
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() WinFormsApp1    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.410\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets    241
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your description you can manually create the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\NuGetPackages` to solve the problem.

[This page](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/error-msb4018-the-resolvepackageassets-task-failed/559252) can give you more information about the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For others who stumbled at the same issue

I managed to overcome the Error by copying the `NuGetPackages` folder

FROM

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages
```

TO

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\
```