# Visual Studio 2022 - Debug Executable Specified in the Debug Profile does not Exist

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I am trying to run a HelloWorld C# .NET Core Console Application and I get this error. I have installed Microsoft VS 2022 and also installed .NET 6.0. Tried all the solutions I could find so far on the other posts regarding this error, but none of them has solved the issue. I also tried reinstalling VS 2022 and even gave VS 2019 a chance to see if things would work differently (they didn't, same error). Does anyone have a solution for this?

**"ResolvePackageAssets" task failed unexpectedly. NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackagingException: Unable to find fallback package folder...**:

[image]

**The debug executable does not exist**:

[image]

Comment: Is NuGet "Package Management", set to `PackageReference` or `Packages.config`? (Tools => Options... => NuGet Package Manager => General =>  Default package management format)

Comment: It is set to Packages.config

Comment: Change it to `PackageReference`. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#project-type-support) for more info.

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing seems to have changed

Comment: Did you close and re-open Visual Studio? You may have to create a new project as well.

Comment: How did you install .NET 6? Open a cmd window and type: `dotnet --info` to check what versions of .NET are installed. If necessary, [Download .NET 6.0 SDK (SDK 6.0.401)](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0). Open **Visual Studio Installer**. Click **Modify**, Click **Individual Components**.  Check both `.NET 6.0 Runtime` and `.NET SDK`.

Comment: I did all the above. I have the right version installed and both .NET 6.0 Runtime and .NET SDK were checked. Re-opening and trying a new project hasn't solved the issue

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your computer? The following may be helpful: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home

Comment: In the error message, I noticed `...Unable to find fallback package folder D:\New Folder\Components\Offline Packages`. What do you see in `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\NuGet\Config\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config`?

Comment: This [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=unable+to+find+fallback+package+folder) seems to yield some results.

Comment: You can try this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73133785/17296043)

Comment: Here is what I see in %ProgramFiles(x86)%\NuGet\Config\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config:                                                                           
                                                                                                                                      
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\"/>
  </packageSources>
</configuration>

Comment: I have also tried what you guys suggested above, and so far, the issue remains unsolved

Comment: Not sure what steps you took to re-install VS 2022, but the following may be useful: [Uninstall or Remove Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/uninstall-visual-studio?view=vs-2022)

Comment: I just posted an answer with how I was able to solve the issue. I couldn't have managed to do it without your suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: Glad you found a workaround. After further research, it seems that this info is stored in a config file.  The following may be helpful to locate it: [Common NuGet configurations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior), [nuget.config reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#fallbackpackagefolders-section), [NuGet documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user9938's suggestion that pointed out the error message I was receiving (**...Unable to find fallback package folder D:\New Folder\Components\Offline Packages**), I solved the issue by simply creating the missing folder indicated. Thank you!